# Alias CC to Refer to Clang in a Shell?

Tags: c, linux, bash, gcc, clang

Any caveats or gotchas to aliasing cc to refer to Clang within my default shell - zsh (presumably by editing my .zshrc file) while leaving cc aliased to gcc in another shell (bash)?

I find Clang much easier to use mainly because it's warnings and error messages are much more readable and understandable than those of gcc. I will be enrolled in a Unix programming course next semester (purely in C) and am expected to have cleared any `gcc -Wall` warnings before submission of an assignment.

What I am trying to do is do most of my developing using Clang within my default shell (zsh) using a makefile that refers to the compiler as just cc. Once satisfied I would run it once, as a test, via bash (invoking gcc as the compiler) before submitting. The submitted makefile with cc as the compiler would then invoke gcc for the instructor, making it transparent to them. I am supposed to submit makefiles with each assignment.

I know this just seems like lazyness since I can re-edit the makefile each time, but I am trying to leave less room for error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just run

```
  make CC=clang
```

or

```
  make CC=gcc
```

or perhaps

```
  make CC='gcc -flto -Wall'
```

(reminder: `-flto` should be passed at compile and at link time).

Answer (score 0):

I won't comment on whether this is fine or not, but there is an easier way.  Just use a variable in your Makefile to whatever you want the default to be:

```
CC=gcc
```

Then you can override this when you invoke make:

```
make CC=clang
```

Comment: I believe that variable assignments passed to `make` command line override those in the `Makefile` so in that case `CC=gcc` is enough in the `Makefile`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: I just checked, and you're absolutely correct.